# Android get video rotation from metatags

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

currently I am using the Android **MediaMetadataRetriever** class in order to get the video rotation tag from a MP4 file, using the **MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION** tag. The main drawback of this, is that is only compatible with API level 17 and up, and the minimum supported API level desired for the application is 14.

Is there any work around for this, I tried using the **ffmpeg** library that used in the project, but I did not find an option to get this tag from the video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It turn outs that **ffmpeg** does actually returns the Rotation from the metadata info of the video using the **-i** option:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original180.mp4':
Metadata:
 major_brand     : isom
 minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: isom3gp4
  creation_time   : 2013-11-05 23:34:58
  Duration: 00:00:24.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16896 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17008 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.96 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 180
  creation_time   : 2013-11-05 23:34:58
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 122 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-11-05 23:34:58
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) has support for the **METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION** tag, I recommend trying that library.

Comment: Well that's good to know, the last time I checked that library it doesn't have support for that Metatag

Comment: It is returning `null`. Testing on samsung galaxy s4.